# How to catch $broadcast in spyOn?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, vue.js

I don't know why my testing is not working.

```
it('should be called when "get-tentative-events" is fired', function() {
  spyOn(this.VM, 'addEvents');
  spyOn(this.VM, 'setEventData').and.returnValue(null);

  this.VM.$root.$broadcast('get-tentative-events', []);
  expect(this.VM.addEvents).toBeDefined();
  expect(this.VM.addEvents).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

In debugging, I confirmed `addEvents` is called.
But there was a error `single-calendar addEvents should be called when "get-tentative-events" is fired FAILED`

FYI:

if I change

```
this.VM.$root.$broadcast('get-tentative-events', []);
```

to

```
this.VM.addEvents([])
```

I can pass this test.So I can not understand why my test is failing.

Answer (score 0):

I always have trouble when spying on Vue methods and events being fired. You can try an async test with `$nextTick` on the off chance Vue's events are resolved async, but I recommend just testing your event handlers directly and trust that Vue's internal event handling works rather spying on those.